# I want to start Android App Development. Dont know where to start

Tags: java, android

I would like to start developing Android Apps, but I have no idea of what languages I should have knowledge of prior to my start. Please list the languages I should have detailed knowledge about as well as languages that bits and pieces there would help me out. I have a base in Java programming, and that is all. If someone could help me to get started, it would be really helpful. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for android you need to know:
java
xml (recommended) - it is for the UI, you can do it with java but it will be harder

to learn java i reccomende TheNewBoston.
he also have android tutorials but learn java first, it will only help :)
the android tutorials are olds but everything that he teaches will work.

in java you need to learn the basics and Threads, extending and implementing (i have no idea how it is called in english).
you should know how to use libraries and how to use everything in the language.

to make it 'short' i will say:
if you like it, it will flow and you will learn it easily. else, you won't